# C++ program to accept multiples inputs and put in an array using pointer

Tags: c++

there's a problem facing me in this question :
"write a c++ console program to accept five 
integers values from keyboard in one line separated by spaces . the program then stores the five values in an array using pointer . then print the elements of the array on the screen ."

I tried to make a string variable and accept 5 integers from user then convert it to integer but it doesn't work well because it doesn't take numbers after space .

any help guys ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string numbers;
    getline(cin, numbers);
    int arr[5];
    int *ptr;
    int values;
    stringstream convert(numbers);
    convert >> values;
    cout << values;


}
```

Comment: I'd personally take each integer obtained by the string stream and use something like `*ptr = thatInt;` to incorporate pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only take one at a time, you need to add more calls to convert like so:

```
  stringstream convert(numbers);
  convert >> values;
  cout << values;
  convert >> values;
  cout << " " << values;
  convert >> values;
  cout << " " << values;
```

The C++faq has a good [section](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/convert-string-to-num.html) on this.

Without major modification, if you need to put the number directly into the array using a pointer, you can do this:

```
int *ptr = arr ;

convert >> *ptr++ ;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;

for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
  cout << arr[i] << " " ;
}
cout << std::endl ;
```

Comment: @AhmedSherif Added code to insert into array using pointer as well

Answer (score 0):

I the numbers variable is string you can search for first non space character using `numbers.find_first_not_of(" ");` 
 and first space character by `numbers.find_first_of(" ");`
 then create a subset using `substr(.....)`
 now place the substr in another string variable.
 Now convert the substring to int.
 repeat the steps for number of times you need. i.e. place the whole code inside a while loop. 
Terminate the loop whenever `numbers.find_first_of(" ");`returns `numbers.end()`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it well, can you explain it with code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully made it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int arr[5];
string number;
cout << "Please enter 5 integers separeted with spaces " << endl;
getline(cin, number);
int *ptr = arr ;
stringstream convert(number);
convert >> *ptr++ ;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;
convert >> *ptr++;

for(  int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
  cout << arr[i] << " " ;
}
cout << std::endl ;
}
```